# Getting method entity object from event listener

Tags: php, symfony

I have an event for the kernel.controller. My question is: Is there any way to get the arguments of the method (in this case the entity object Lead) from this event, or from any other?

```
/**
 * @Route("/view/{id}", name="lead_view")
 */
public function view(Lead $lead) :Response {
    ///....
}


public function onKernelController(ControllerEvent $event): void
{

    $params = $event->getRequest()->attributes->get('_route_params');
}
```

I understand that maybe the conversion to the entity object is done after the kernel.controller event, is it possible to get it from the kernel.response event?

Thanks

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/events.html#kernel-controller-arguments

Comment: @ArleighHix thank you